# How to Connect IoT device to the remote monitoring preconfigured solution (Windows)? How to implement and specify the behaviour of IoT hub device?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-suite/iot-suite-connecting-devices#create-a-c-sample-solution-on-windows

**Add the following functions that execute when the device receives the SetTemperature and SetHumidity commands from IoT Hub:**

```
 EXECUTE_COMMAND_RESULT SetTemperature(Thermostat* thermostat, int temperature)
 {
   (void)printf("Received temperature %d\r\n", temperature);
   thermostat->Temperature = temperature;
   return EXECUTE_COMMAND_SUCCESS;
 }

 EXECUTE_COMMAND_RESULT SetHumidity(Thermostat* thermostat, int humidity)
 {
   (void)printf("Received humidity %d\r\n", humidity);
   thermostat->Humidity = humidity;
   return EXECUTE_COMMAND_SUCCESS;
 }
```

**Add the following function that sends a message to IoT Hub:**

```
 static void sendMessage(IOTHUB_CLIENT_HANDLE iotHubClientHandle, const unsigned char* buffer, size_t size)
 {
   IOTHUB_MESSAGE_HANDLE messageHandle = IoTHubMessage_CreateFromByteArray(buffer, size);
   if (messageHandle == NULL)
   {
     printf("unable to create a new IoTHubMessage\r\n");
   }
   else
   {
     if (IoTHubClient_SendEventAsync(iotHubClientHandle, messageHandle, NULL, NULL) != IOTHUB_CLIENT_OK)
     {
       printf("failed to hand over the message to IoTHubClient");
     }
     else
     {
       printf("IoTHubClient accepted the message for delivery\r\n");
     }

 IoTHubMessage_Destroy(messageHandle);
   }
 free((void*)buffer);
 }
```

**More in given link**

Comment: What, exactly, is your question? Looks like you just copy&pasted parts of a published tutorial, with no question described.

Comment: How to deploy code which is given in a link.

Answer (score 0):

The [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-suite/iot-suite-connecting-devices#create-a-c-sample-solution-on-windows) you're referring to here shows you how to build and run this sample code on a Windows desktop machine using Visual Studio. There are two other equivalent articles that show you how to run the same code on a [Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-suite/iot-suite-connecting-devices-linux) machine or an [mbed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-suite/iot-suite-connecting-devices-mbed) device.

If you want to follow an in-depth tutorial on how to use another hardware device such as a Raspberry Pi or Intel Edison with Azure IoT Hub, then take a look at the collection of IoT Hub tutorials in the **Get started** folder [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/).